# Is it possible to delete the revision history in a Google Spreadsheet or Doc?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible to delete the revision history in a Google Spreadsheet / Doc?

I've added some information into a shared Google Doc that I own that I don't want in there, I've deleted the data, but its still viewable if you go into the revision history. Is there a way to delete / clear the revision history other than making a copy of the document and re-sharing it, essentially as a new document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to delete revisions on the revision history of Google spreadsheets / documents. As the OP already figured out, the workaround is to make a copy of the file.